# XAML and MVVMLight custom animation

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I'm trying to achieve a open/close navigation like the one that exists in the instagram app in W10 mobile, using MVVMLight and without breaking the MVVM Pattern.

I have a shell which has a frame, and I want to click a button in a page placed in that frame that opens a "sub-window" right to left.

Any ideias?

Comment: Do you have a gif/video/image example of what you're after, even if it's just a simple sketch of the transition you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a panel with both windows and set the visibility of one to hidden.
Bind it's visibility to a property on the ViewModel.
When you click the button, set visibility to `True`, and have a wpf animation so it'll "Slide" in / out .

Answer (score 0):

One of my idea is to create a window using a datatemplate, so in your mainwindow.xaml, you would have something like

```
<Window ..    
    <Grid>
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Window1}"/> 
       <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Window2}"/>    
    </Grid>
/>
```

From there, perhaps you can have a boolean property to check if that property is true, then set visibility to visible, else, set the visibility to collapsed/hidden. In case you need, here is the converter for booleantovisibility(just in case you need it)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace FaceTheWall.converters
{
    class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Boolean && (bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the example of how you can use the booleantovisibility converter in xaml

```
<TextBox...
     Visibility="{Binding ButtCancel, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
... >
</TextBox
```